# How do I include service packs in PSWindowsUpdate?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am using this tool to manage nightly updates of certain machines:

```
Get-WUUpdates -ForceDownload -ForceInstall -AutoReboot -AcceptAll
```

However, the command does not install service packs, such as 1903. Is there a way to trigger the installation of feature updates as well?

Comment: It may not be offered for you particular PC for many reasons but you can install it manually, this page will allow you to download the latest w10 version and install it at some point when it done downloading the iso....https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @moab Well I am trying to automate something, download manually wasn't the answer I was looking for. The update is offered, I just need an automatic way so I don't have to manually install 100 ThinkCentre, because the boss does not want to pay for the CAL's to setup a WSUS.

Comment: It might be compatibility holds set by Microsoft, scroll down a bit....https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-resolves-six-windows-10-1903-issues-update-blocks-stay-on/

Comment: Windows 10 version 1903 is not considered a service pack, it’s a full Windows release, technically there isn’t an update you can download.  What any machine downloads is the entire feature update image itself.  Something like SCCM should be used to push feature updates.